# Apache Camel ElasticSearch Delete Operation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-camel

I 'm using Apache Camel Elasticsearch 2 and I would like to delete a record.

I searched the documentation but I'm not getting any handle on examples on delete operation, I'm able to save a record in ElasticSearch with the below code though.

Save Operation:

```
from("direct:index")
.process(fooSaveProcessor)
.to("elasticsearch://local?operation=INDEX&indexName=twitter&indexType=tweet");
```

In FooSaveProcessor.java

```
public class FooSaveProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        Foo foo = exchange.getIn().getBody(Foo.class);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(ElasticsearchConstants.PARAM_INDEX_ID, foo.id);
        String jsonStr = convertToJSON(foo);
        log.info("Input to Elastic " + jsonStr);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(jsonStr);
    }

}
```

But I'm unable to perform delete operation with below code

Delete Operation:

```
from("direct:index")
.process(fooDeleteProcessor)
.to("elasticsearch://local?operation=DELETE&indexName=twitter&indexType=tweet");
```

In fooDeleteProcessor.java

```
public class FooDeleteProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        Foo foo = exchange.getIn().getBody(Foo.class);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(ElasticsearchConstants.PARAM_INDEX_ID, foo.id);
    }

}
```

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-azure-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-elasticsearch-rest-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Can someone please help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Camel ElasticSearch component [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/elasticsearch.html), in order for the DELETE operation to work, the body of the Exchange needs to be the index id to delete. As such, you should change your processor to something like this:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) {
    Foo foo = exchange.getIn().getBody(Foo.class);
    exchange.getOut().setBody(foo.id);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not been able to respond sooner. I tried many times to accept your answer but in vain. I keep getting this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Just did it. Thank you!